# Initiator and acceptor on different OS

Tags: c++, tcp, quickfix

I have to run my initiator and acceptor on two different OS. I am seeing a weird problem of socket disconnection. Following are the different scenarios I have tried. I am using C++/Quickfix. I have been using the setup on Debian/Ubuntu for a long time, no issues. With CentOS and Ubuntu connection establishment is giving a problem. 
Details of the problem:-

### Scenario-1 (Problem Scenario)

My initiator is running on Machine-1 which is CentOS

My acceptor is running on Machine-2 which is Ubuntu

When I try to connect, I am getting following error:-

```
<20121213-03:57:41.619, FIX.4.2:ft-trade->ES, event>
  (Connecting to 10.0.0.40 on port 31209)
<20121213-03:57:41.620, FIX.4.2:ft-trade->ES, outgoing>
  (8=FIX.4.2 9=77 35=A 34=1 49=ft-trade 52=20121213-03:57:41.620 56=ES 98=0 108=30 141=Y 10=230 )
<20121213-03:57:41.620, FIX.4.2:ft-trade->ES, event>
  (Initiated logon request)
<20121213-03:57:41.621, FIX.4.2:ft-trade->ES, event>
  (Socket Error: Connection reset by peer.)
<20121213-03:57:41.621, FIX.4.2:ft-trade->ES, event>
  (Disconnecting)
```

Please do not go by the checksum field in above packet, as I had to change the sender/target compids before posting here.

### Scenario-2 (Works fine)

I took the same initiator code to a different Machine-3. Both Ubuntu now.

From Machine-3, I can successfully connect to Machine-2.

This scenario had no issues, so my settings file etc. are all good.

### Scenario-3 (Works fine)

I took the same acceptor code to Machine-1. Both CentOS now

Again, I could succesfully connect.

I also checked if there could be any firewall related issues. But there is no problem since, telnet from Machine-1 to Machine-2 is successful.

As I understand, this is a TCP/IP error when the peer disconnects or closes the socket after opening it. But the way message comes in, its not sure if the error is because of TCP/IP or quickfix. I do not see any reason for TCP/IP handshake problem since TELNET also works fine.

Comment: A closed socket may also mean that the other side has crashed and closed the connection before sending any other reply. Any error messages, logs, exceptions on the acceptor side?

Comment: No, application has not crashed. Looks something specific to quickfix.

Comment: You still have to check the acceptor-side logs to see why the acceptor ends the connection. Can't help without any clues

Comment: quickfix logs are 0 bytes size